# How to disable horizontal scrolling when the mobile navigation is pulled out?

Tags: css, scroll

I want to have the drag-out navigation like there is on [touch.facebook.com](http://touch.facebook.com) and my (simplified) markup is showcased on [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jX24f/).

When the navigation is shown, the browsers can scroll to the end of the content on the right side, as witnessed by the horizontal scrollbar that appears. Not a problem on the desktops really, but on mobile devices you might accidentally drag it to the right and it looks really clumsy.

The only working solution I know of for this situation is to give the document a `overflow-x:hidden;`. But for some reason, if I do that, vertical scrolling no longer fires jQuery's `scroll` event. So I have to find another CSS solution to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out the problem was giving the `html` element `height:100%`. Once that was removed, and `overflow-x:hidden;` was applied to `body` again, both situations were successfully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body` tag instead of `html`?

Comment: Kinda, sorta, but i actually figured out something else that was causing the problem, will post the answer (i don't have enough reputation to give you a vote up for a useful suggestion)

Comment: Haha no worries, glad you figured it out!